# Getting SSL Error while accessing SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/sentence-t5-base')

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, sentence-transformers

I am executing the below code in the python3.8 terminal which is inside of seclab VM

```
>>> from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
>>> st_model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/sentence-t5-base')
```

Getting below error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 87, in __init__
    snapshot_download(model_name_or_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/util.py", line 442, in snapshot_download
    model_info = _api.model_info(repo_id=repo_id, revision=revision, token=token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 94, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_deprecation.py", line 98, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/huggingface_hub/hf_api.py", line 1283, in model_info
    r = requests.get(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/models/sentence-transformers/sentence-t5-base (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

tried the below steps:
Step1:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Step2:

```
os.environ["CURL_CA_BUNDLE"] = ""
```

The above steps didn't work for me.
Any idea how to disable the SSL certificate issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out on this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Solved by opening new terminal and it worked for me.